# Instantiate Java Spring repository interface without @Autowire

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, interface, repository

This is my Spring repository interface.

```
@Repository
public interface WebappRepository extends CrudRepository<myModel, Long> {

}
```

In my controller, I can instantiate the `WebappRepository` even though it's an interface, because of Spring annotation magic.

```
public class controller{

    @Autowire
    WebappRepository repo;

    public controller(){

    }
}
```

But this variant, using the constructor, does *not* work, and rightly so, because WebappRepository is an interface.

```
public class controller{

    WebappRepository repo;

    public controller(){
        this.repo = new WebappRepository();
    }
}
```

Olivier Gierke himself [advocates to avoid `@Autowire` fields at all costs](http://olivergierke.de/2013/11/why-field-injection-is-evil/). How can I "instantiate" the repository interface in my Spring application while avoiding the `@Autowire`?

Comment: They advocate against field injection. Just use constructor injection. The mechanism Spring uses for generating a `WebappRepository` instance is quite complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inject dependencies in constructor:

```
@Component
public class Controller{


    WebappRepository repo;

    @Autowire
    public Controller(WebappRepository repo){
        this.repo = repo;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to add `@Component` or `@Service` annotation on the controller class.( And please start the class name with capital letter.) If you have only one constructor in your class you can get rid of `@Autowire` annotation.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Spring 4.3+ and your target class has just one constructor, you can omit autowired annotation. Spring will inject all the needed dependencies for it.
So writing just below constructor would suffice:

```
public controller(WebappRepository repo){
    this.repo = repo;
}
```

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation